# What's the strategy used by sort when field not found?

Tags: linux, command-line, sorting

I got a file named test, its content is like

```
111 222
11 22
111 223
12 22 33
11 2 25
222 331
11 2
33 2 1
33
33 22 33
```

I used：

```
sort -bk2.3 test
```

But the result confused me, those lines which doesn't have k2.3 are in a rather random sort. I'm expecting the target lines all listed at the beginning or the end, but it's not. It's like:

```
11 2
11 22
33
222 331
33 2 1
111 222
11 2 25
111 223
12 22 33
33 22 33
```

So, what's the inner mechanism of sort to rank those lines without a claimed key area?

Comment: explain please more detailed which sort you would like to have.

Comment: Interesting. It is not random and not dependent on the original line order, as `sort test | sort -bk2.3` gives the same output order, but I can't see any pattern. I also find `sort test` unexpected, with the **111** lines preceding the **11** lines, as though blank is later in the collating sequence than alphanumerics (I repeated with **A** instead of **1**, etc, in the test file). All very puzzling.

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov, the practical file is much more hard to read, and I simplified it here

Comment: I mean could you please explain your intention, how you would like to sort - by what criteria?

Comment: @Ruslan Gerasimov, I expected 'sort' command can range the target lines together, whether at the beginning or tail of the output, instead of let them spread everywhere.

Comment: I know, that you got some spreading, but what is your particular requirement to sorting, what did you want to get after the command executed?

Comment: a shopping times which is embedded in a long string

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998627/sorting-with-multiple-keys-with-linux-sort-command) on the same topic. This behavior of sort is not intuitive, and despite studying both that thread and the official [GNU Sort documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) I can't determine exactly what happens when a sort index is out of bounds.

1. However, I must point out that you can use the "b" modifier as a sort
   key opt which ignores whitespace in that key, i.e. blank keys eg

   $ sort -k 2.3nb test
2. Also from the [GNU Sort documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html), it's clear the -k option
   takes an argument of the format *start pos*,*end pos* and if no *end
   pos* is specified it compares keys from your starting position
   *until the end of the current line*. This, together with the following caution are what's resulting in the undefined behavior.

   ```
   Finally, as a last resort when all keys compare equal, 
   sort compares entire lines as if no ordering options other 
   than --reverse (-r) were specified.
   ```
3. You can also specify multiple keys to act as a tie-breaker, though this doesn't solve for your use case because it's the first key that's causing the unintuitive behavior.
4. Finally, if you have the --debug option available on your system as
   per the GNU Sort  that would be much help troubleshooting because it reveals what is being matched with the key pattern. Unfortunately I didn't and so had to experiment in the dark.

I don't know what your use case is exactly, but I found a rather pleasing result set with the following. *This behavior is likely not documented* but observably seems to work as per my intuition and your request:

```
$ sort -k 2.3nb,2 test
11 2
11 2 25
11 22
12 22 33
33
33 2 1
33 22 33
222 331
111 222
111 223
```